# Acceder a los archivos de una carpeta en Kotlin

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

Estoy haciendo una aplicación que sea capaz de abrir archivos pdf para su posterior uso, pero a la hora de acceder al directorio de descargas del teléfono, solo se muestran las carpetas pero el resto de archivos no.

He descartado la idea de que sea de la ruta, ya que es capaz de mostrar las carpetas:

`listarDocumentos(File(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS))`

```
private fun listarDocumentos(directory: File) {
        directory.walk().forEach {
            println(it)
        }
}
```

Cuando ejecuto este código solo me muestra las carpetas y necesito los archivos pdf...
Gracias por la ayuda!!

Answer (score 0):

El problema se debe a que al usar

```
File(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)
```

con las nuevas versiones de Android no es posible acceder a esa ruta, de hecho puedes probar de la siguiente forma:

```
 val directory = File(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)
        if (directory.exists()) {
            println("Existe")
        }else{
            println("NO Existe")
        }
```

Si deseas leer lo archivos anteriormente se podìa realizar con

```
val downloadsFolder = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
   
            if (downloadsFolder != null) {
                listarDocumentos(downloadsFolder)
            }
```

pero el mètodo `getExternalStoragePublicDirectory()` es obsoleto.

**Ahora por seguridad los archivos deberan ser leidos dentro de la estructura que se crea para tu aplicaciòn** y si vas a leer el directorio `DOWNLOADS` aquì se guardarìan

```
/data/"package name"/files/Download
```

y debes leerlos de esta forma usando `getExternalFilesDir()` y tu funcion `listarDocumentos()` :

```
 val downloadsFolder  = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)
      
        if (downloadsFolder != null) {
            listarDocumentos(downloadsFolder)
        }
```